# Missing Test Analyzer reports on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, continuous-integration

In my project I enabled `Publish JUnit test result report` in `Post-build Actions` but after a build there is no Test Analyzer Report.

Is there is any solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide your build script and build log for the project? My best guess with the information you provided is that the unit test(s) failed to run, or a dependency is missing. Also verify that your XML files are being created in the directory you specified (e.g., build/reports/junit/*.xml).

Answer (score 0):

If your console output for the build for a project (e.g., "my-project") creates a JUnit reports folder like:

```
[mkdir] Created dir: /usr/share/tomcat8/.jenkins/jobs/my-project/workspace/build/reports/junit
```

Then you should have your `Test report XMLs` option set to `build/reports/junit/*.xml` as follows:

[image: Jenkins - Publish JUnit test result report]

You can also browse your Workspace after a build to locate the path of the JUnit reports:

[image: Jenkins Workspace - JUnit Reports]